# Make prediction with Keras model using multiple CPUs

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am trying to make predictions with a Keras model (using Tensorflow 2.0) using multiple CPUs.

I have tried this:
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(4)
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(4)

While not getting an error, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Can predictions be multithreaded?

Many thanks

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue in the end?