# How to make predictions in parallel using sequential Keras model and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I'm trying to solve a binary-classification problem. I therefore created a model in Keras (with a TensorFlow backend) and trained the model on CPU. I saved the model in the TensorFlow SavedModel format using the Keras API. I'm using Kaggle Kernels with Python 3.7.6, Keras 2.4.3 and TensorFlow 2.3.0.

Here's the simplified code I used along with some mockup data (in reality I'm training my model on a GPU but I believe the issue I face is independet of that fact):

```
# setup
import numpy as np

random_state = 0

# create mockup data
train_labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000))
validation_labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(200))
train_features = np.random.rand(1000, 49)
validation_features = np.random.rand(200, 49)

# create and train model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

dim = train_features.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dim, input_dim=dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2, seed=random_state))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')
model.summary()

epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, validation_data=(validation_features, validation_labels))

# evaluate model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

prediction_labels = model.predict_classes(validation_features)
print(confusion_matrix(prediction_labels, validation_labels))

# save model
model.save('/kaggle/working/model')
```

I then load the model in a new session. When I make a prediction on a single CPU it works just fine. What I actually want to do, however, is making predictions on all 4 available CPUs in parallel (in contrast to my mockup here, the actual problem I'm trying to solve is much more complicated and much more data is involved). I tried to do this using `multiprocessing` like so:

```
# setup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random_state = 0

# load model
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('../input/repro-model/model')

# create mockup test data
test_features = np.random.rand(1000, 49)

# make some test predictions on the entire test set and a single observation
model.predict_classes(test_features)
model.predict_classes(test_features[[0]])

# set up test dataframe for making predictions in parallel
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_features)

seq_ids = []
for i in np.arange(1,201):
    seq_id = [i] * 5
    seq_ids.append(seq_id)

frm_ids = [np.arange(1,6)] * 200

test_df['seq_id'] = [item for sublist in seq_ids for item in sublist]
test_df['frm_id'] = [item for sublist in frm_ids for item in sublist]

# test the setup
seq_id = 1
frm_id = 1

model.predict_classes(test_df[(test_df.seq_id == seq_id) & (test_df.frm_id == frm_id)].drop(['seq_id', 'frm_id'], axis=1))

# create function for making predictions
def make_prediction(model, data, seq_id, frm_id):
    
    print(seq_id)
    
    pred = model.predict_classes(data[(data.seq_id == seq_id) & (data.frm_id == frm_id)].drop(['seq_id', 'frm_id'], axis=1))

    return pred

# make test prediction
make_prediction(model, test_df, 1, 1)

# make predictions in parallel
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

workers = 4
p = Pool(processes=workers)

seq_list, frm_list = np.arange(1, 201), np.arange(1, 6)
id_pair_list = list(itertools.product(seq_list, frm_list))

predictions = p.starmap(make_prediction, [(model, test_df, id_pair[0], id_pair[1]) for id_pair in id_pair_list])
p.close()
```

When I run the code above I get the following stacktrace and error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-52e9e388daba> in <module>
      8 id_pair_list = list(itertools.product(seq_list, frm_list))
      9 
---> 10 predictions = p.starmap(make_prediction, [(model, test_df, id_pair[0], id_pair[1]) for id_pair in id_pair_list])
     11 p.close()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    274         `func` and (a, b) becomes func(a, b).
    275         '''
--> 276         return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
    277 
    278     def starmap_async(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None, callback=None,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    429                         break
    430                     try:
--> 431                         put(task)
    432                     except Exception as e:
    433                         job, idx = task[:2]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in send(self, obj)
    204         self._check_closed()
    205         self._check_writable()
--> 206         self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    207 
    208     def recv_bytes(self, maxlength=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py in dumps(cls, obj, protocol)
     49     def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
     50         buf = io.BytesIO()
---> 51         cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
     52         return buf.getbuffer()
     53 

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

After reading everything on this topic I found on SO (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725323/keras-tensorflow-exception-while-predicting-from-multiple-threads?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136293/running-keras-model-for-prediction-in-multiple-threads) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900246/tensorflow-passing-a-session-to-a-python-multiprocess)) and GitHub (e.g., [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34697), and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10528) and [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1126)) I figured that there is some issue with pickling my sequential Keras model and multithreading. I then tried to load the model within my prediction function and delete it after each predict function call like so:

```
def make_prediction(data, seq_id, frm_id):
    
    print(seq_id)
    
    from keras.models import load_model
    model = load_model('../input/repro-model/model')
    
    pred = model.predict_classes(data[(data.seq_id == seq_id) & (data.frm_id == frm_id)].drop(['seq_id', 'frm_id'], axis=1))
    
    del model
    
    return pred

from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

workers = 4
p = Pool(processes=workers)

seq_list, frm_list = np.arange(1, 201), np.arange(1, 6)
id_pair_list = list(itertools.product(seq_list, frm_list))

predictions = p.starmap(make_prediction, [(test_df, id_pair[0], id_pair[1]) for id_pair in id_pair_list])
p.close()
```

I don't get an error anymore but the process hangs when the starmap function call is executed when the first four predictions are made. So there must be some issue remaining. Using `model._make_predict_function()` doesn't work as it seems to be [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850089/is-keras-thread-safe/43393252#43393252). There are also quite a few posts on SO on this topic that are unanswered: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942789/multiprocessing-predictions-in-keras-model), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974483/make-prediction-with-keras-model-using-multiple-cpus) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657013/python-multiprocessing-with-keras-prediction).

Does anyone have an idea how I could parallelize making predictions with my sequential Keras model on CPU? That would be awesome since I'm stuck with this issue for quite a while already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please add the tensorflow version you are using.

Comment: TensorFlow 2.3.0. Thanks for having a look at my question! I'll check your suggestion.

Comment: I had the same issue with tf 2.3.0. But the solution presented below works for 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Adding this Code-Snippet helped me to solve the issue (but only for tf version 2.0.0)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import saving_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize, serialize

def unpack(model, training_config, weights):
    restored_model = deserialize(model)
    if training_config is not None:
        restored_model.compile(**saving_utils.compile_args_from_training_config(
        training_config))
    restored_model.set_weights(weights)
    return restored_model


def make_keras_picklable():
    def __reduce__(self):
        model_metadata = saving_utils.model_metadata(self)
        training_config = model_metadata.get("training_config", None)
        model = serialize(self)
        weights = self.get_weights()
        return unpack, (model, training_config, weights)

cls = tf.keras.models.Model
cls.__reduce__ = __reduce__


# Ensures that tf.keras models are pickable
make_keras_picklable()
```

Comment: What imports do I need to make your code run? I get the following error: NameError: name '__reduce__' is not defined.

Comment: I added the imports. I hope these are all you need. There are much more in my entire code. I tried to sort out which are relevant for the snippet above. Please let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you. I tried your snippet again, but get another error now: NameError: name '__reduce__' is not defined.